# How to return T in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to return T in the function.

I have an interface class `IRepository.kt`

```
interface IRepository
{
    fun <T>Save(model:T)
    fun <T>Delete(model:T)
    fun <T>Get(id:Long):T
}
```

I want to implement in `Repolmpl.kt`

```
class Repolmpl:IRepository
{

  override fun <T>Delete(model:T)
  {
      println("$model  : Save}")
  }

  override fun <T>Get(id:Long):T
  {
      return T //ERROR here I want to return T...
  }

  override fun <T> Save(model: T) 
  {
      println("$model : Delete")
  }
}
```

I saw some similar questions online but I just can't find the right solution.

Comment: Could you edit the code so it tries to return value (T is the type, right?). What error do you get then?

Comment: `T` is a type. If you have return type `T`, you should return a value of type `T`, not the Type itself.

Answer (score 2):

A generic type `T` is basically just a template. You cannot return it but have to replace it with an actual type first. Make the interface itself generic, not its methods. When implementing, specify `T`:

```
interface IRepository<T> {
    fun save(model: T)
    fun delete(model: T)
    fun get(id: Long): T
}

class Repolmpl: IRepository<String>
{
    override fun delete(model: String) {}
    override fun get(id: Long): String {}
    override fun save(model: String) {}
}
```

Comment: But now whole repo is binded to String. Sometimes there is an legitimate reason to make methods generic, not whole class, and specify them during invocation. For example - your repo can return `Dog`, `Cat` and `Cow`. With your solution you have to create repo per type, instead of `get<Dog>(dogId)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just return `T`. `T` is type here, and it is like `return String`.

You have to return *instance of T*. So, sth like:

```
class Repo {
    val data = mapOf<Long, Any>()

    // ...    

    fun <T> get(id: Long): T {
        return data[id] as T // Get data from somewhere and then cast it to expected type
    }
}
```